# Need 301 redirect rule in .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I about to change an ecommerce store over from oscommerce to magento.

I have kept the url structure the same but need to rewrite the product and category urls.

I need this:

`some-product-url-p-123.html`

to be written to this:

`some-product-url.html`

and the category is the same principle:

`some-category-url-c-123.html`

to:

`some-category-url.html`

I have been trying to work this out and have spent hours looking but can't find anything. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern should work for you:-

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)?-[pc]-\d+\.html$         $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have tried this and it returns a 404 when I tested it.

Comment: @etrade there must be something else going on as that Regex is spot on. If you browse to `some-category-url-c-123.html` what do you get?

Comment: Not sure what Im doing wrong then. My old site is www.yeltsa.com

This url http://www.yeltsa.com/avtex-12v-tv-dvd-combo-c-7219.html for example should change to http://www.yeltsa.com/avtex-12v-tv-dvd-combo.html when the site goes live. Im currently testing it here, www.dev.yeltsa.com

If i visit this url http://www.dev.yeltsa.com/avtex-12v-tv-dvd-combo-c-7219.html it should direct to the new url but I just get a 404 and it stays on the same page.

Comment: Maybe i have inserted the rewrite rule in the wrong place but i have it just after the rewrite base as shown above.